# Jquery : add class to a div, same as another div have

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to target a div's class and that class want to apply to another div.

I cant write directly class name as that class can change after every minute.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

code

```
<div class="one" id="one"></div>
<div class="here I want to apply the class which id one is having"></div>
```

Note: these divs are not close to each other.

Comment: @Arun P Johny : why you guys have voted to close this question ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose Div1 has any class and you want same class on Div2. So try this :

```
jQuery('#div2').addClass(jQuery('#div1').attr('class'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It was easy but got stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some jQuery element `el`, you can add its class to another object `target` very simply, like this:

```
target.addClass(el.attr("class"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a div as below

```
<div class="myClass" id="myId">

</div>
```

and you want to add the class named "myClass" to the following div

```
<div id="secondId">

</div>
```

You could get the class of the first div by using

```
var myclass = $('#myId').attr('class') //gets the class name of that div
```

To add the class to your target div use

```
$('#secondId').addClass(myclass)
```

Hope that helps u mate.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
var classes = $("#one").attr("class");
$("#one").next().addClass(classes);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
<div class="one" id="one"></div>
<div id="target" class="here I want to apply the class which id one is having"></div>

var source = document.getElementById('one');
var target = document.getElementById('target');
target.className = source.className;

/// If you want to append the classes of source, then 
    target.className += " "+source.className;
```

Comment: Good one but too lengthy.